# Finding an example where the sum of iid rv's is infinite almost surely

Tags: probability-theory

$Y_1, Y_2, \dots$ are iid non-negative random variables. Let $S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha^n Y_n$, where $\alpha \in (0,1)$. Now, $EY < \infty$ implies that $S < \infty$ almost surely.

Can anyone give an example where $S=\infty$ almost surely by removing the $EY<\infty$ constraint? Thanks!

Comment: Let $Y_k$ take the value $2^n$ with probability ${1 \over 2^n}$, for $n=1,...$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $Y_1$ is such that $\mathbb P\{|Y_1|>t\}\geqslant 1/\log t$ for $t$ large enough. Then for all $A$ the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\mathbb P\{\alpha^n|Y_n|>A\}$ is divergent and using the Borel-Cantelli lemma we obtain that $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\alpha^nY_n$ is almost surely divergent.